# how to add programmatical code into a .aspx file in a visual basic asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, asp-classic

I have a visual basic 2013 asp.net web application project.

So far, my code is all in the .aspx.vb   file.

How can visual basic code be put into the .aspx file itself (Like in classic ASP.)
to programmatically control the HTML?

For example, how would I programmatically add a loop that shows multiple simple HTML labels?
While 

End While

Comment: Can I just ask why?  Really you should use the code behind for the application; mixing the two isn't best practice...  (It's still possible to manipulate the HTML if you add the `id` and `runat="server"` attributes to the HTML you want to control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same as classic asp, just add this <% %>

example

```
<body>
<% For x As Integer = 0 To 10 %>
<%=x%><br />
<% Next %>
</body>
```

In asp.net, if your controls have runat="server" then you can access them through the code behind (the .vb file).

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Language attribute as VB or C#. For more information see the below code for understating. Create one Webpage name as "WebForm1".

code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" %>
```

Regards,
Sekhar